# Script to delete content older than x days

Tags: command-line, delete

I have the following script, though I would like to change it to deleting content once the directory reaches a certain size. What are my options?

```
find /home/scott/google-drive/CAMMEDIA/* -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: do you mean date or size?? I would prefere for date to use -mmin instead of -mtime, example delete all files older than 24h -mmin +1440, works better than -mtime.

Comment: Thanks, @WiKrle. I was referring to folder size. Thanks for the suggestive change.

Comment: Hi Scott, so just add the `-size`flag with your needed parameters, I would also add the `-type`to search only for directories and not for files if you want that. So as an example search for all directories bigger than 10K you need this `find /place/to/search -type d -size +10K`and then you can continue however you like.

Comment: @WiKrle, in this scenario, what directory is -size for? I'm looking to watch the total size of CAMMEDIA.

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code. You will have to set the folder size and what you want to remove yourself (you were not clear on what you wanted to be removed so I'm running the same thing you were)

```
MAX_SIZE=50000
DIR_SIZE=$(du /home/scott/google-drive/CAMMEDIA/*)
if [$MAXSIZE -gt $DIR_SIZE]
then
    find /home/scott/google-drive/CAMMEDIA/* -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
fi
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeff. I assume this is in KB?

Comment: @Scott yes,
from the man page: "Display values are in units of the first available SIZE from --block-size, and the DU_BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE and BLOCKSIZE environment variables.  Otherwise, units default to 1024
       bytes (or 512 if POSIXLY_CORRECT is set)".

You can get a human-readable format by using `du -h` but I think you will want the raw number for your code. 

If this answer works for you please upvote and accept it.

Comment: I'm receiving an error message in running this now...line 3: [: missing `]'. BTW, I changed 'than' to 'then'.

Comment: can you address the error I'm receiving?

Comment: Try putting spaces between the variable and the bracket. `if [ $MAXSIZE -gt $DIR_SIZE ] `